# Python subprocess calls hang?

Tags: python

Do subprocess calls in Python hang? That is, do subprocess calls operate in the same thread as the rest of the Python code, or is it a non-blocking model? I couldn't find anything in the docs or on SO on the matter. Thanks!

Comment: Which subprocess function are you referring to?

Comment: For example, `subprocess.call(["./myOtherScript"])`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most methods in the `subprocess` module are blocking, meaning that they want for the subprocess to complete before returning. However, [`subprocess.Popen`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-objects) is non-blocking.

```
result = subprocess.call(cmd) # This will block until cmd is complete
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd) # This will return a Popen object right away
```

Once you have the `Popen` object, you can use the [`poll`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.poll) instance method to see if the subprocess is complete without blocking.

```
if p.poll() is None: # Make sure you check against None, since it could return 0 when the process is complete.
    print "Process is still running"
```

Comment: What about if I append an `&` to the end of `cmd`?

Comment: @goodcow if you do that along with `shell=True`, it won't block. I would recommend just using `Popen` directly instead, though.

Answer (score 2):

subprocesses run in the background. In the subprocess module, there is a class called Popen that starts a process in the background. It has a wait() method you can use to wait for the process to finish. It also has a communicate() helper method that will handle stdin/stdout/stderr plus wait for the process to complete. It also has convenience functions like call() and check_call() that create a Popen object and then wait for it to complete.

So, subprocess implements a non-blocking model but also gives you blocking helper functions.